# Update C# Chart using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, charts

I am currently trying to update a chart which is on my form to the background worker using:

```
bwCharter.RunWorkerAsync(chart1);
```

Which runs:

```
private void bcCharter_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart = null;

     // Convert e.Argument to chart
     //..
     // Converted..

     chart.Series.Clear();
     e.Result=chart;

     setChart(c.chart);
}
private void setChart(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart arg)
{
     if (chart1.InvokeRequired)
     {
         chart1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { setChart(arg); }));
         return;
     }

     chart1 = arg;
}
```

However, at the point of clearing the series, an exception is thrown.

Basically, I want to do a whole lot more processing after clearing the series, which slows the GUI down completely - so wanted this in another thread.

I thought that by passing it as an argument, I should be safe, but apparently not!

Interestingly, the chart is on a tab page. I can run this over and over if the tabpage is in the background, but if I run this, look at the chart, hide it again, and re-run, it throws the exception. Obviously, it throws if the chart is in the foreground as well.

Can anyone suggest what I can do differently?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:
I know that this can be done in the form thread, as when I assign it back again. However the whole point of using a background worker is to avoid grinding the whole program to a halt. As I said, there is a lot more processing than just this one command.

I assumed that passing it as an argument would allow me to access it in that thread unhindered, but is there a chance that this passed chart still points back to the original chart in some way? If so, how can this be overcome?

I want to block the GUI thread as little as possible - so there seems no point in just invoking every command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to clear it first, then do a lot of asynchronous work before you redisplay it, why don't you call `chart.Series.Clear();` before you invoke the `BackgroundWorker`? In that case it gets cleared on the main UI thread, then you perform som async work before you again set the chart from the UI thread.

Also, when using a `BackgroundWorker`, I would use the inbuilt `ReportProgress` and WorkerCompleted events to avoid the manual cross-thread invoking. That's part of the reason of using the `BackgroundWorker` in the first place to get this kind of functionality for *"free"*. So setting the chart should be done in the WorkerCompleted to simplify your code (even if that is not the source of the problem in this case).

Comment: The problem is that there is a lot more processing than just that to do. The reason I wanted a backgroundworker was to keep the GUI responsive. So there is no advantage if I call the backgroundworker, just to tell it to do everything in the GUI thread. What I was hoping for was to copy the chart, let the background worker process it, then pass it back and set the new chart in the place of the old one. Is this not possible?

Comment: Can't you just let the BackgroundWorker do all the work, and then in the WorkerCompleted event clear the old chart and insert the new one? If you set the e.Result to the new chart, it's available from the WorkerCompleted method also.

Comment: The same thing happens. The problem is not when I try to assign the chart (this is invoked in the GUI thread, as shown above). The problem is with manipulating the chart, which was passed as an argument. Could it be that even though the chart was passed, it is still only seeing the original object? Surely this would be the case only if it were passed as a reference?

Comment: It's only the reference that is passed, so any action you do to the passed reference will impact the original object that belongs to the GUI thread.

Comment: I see! Well that makes more sense then - do you know if there is any way to modify this behaviour? Also, what then is the use of using 'ref', or is this only the case with backgroundworkers?

Comment: The object you send as parameter is sent by value, but the object itself is a reference to the actal object. Therefore for example setting sender = null inside the method will not make the object that was sent as parameter equals null, but any change done to sender will be reflected upon the sender as well. The ref keyword will send a reference to the reference, so setting this to null makes the original reference null as well. Nothing special with backgroundworkers. This happens for all reference type objects. For value type (like int, long and any structs you have created yourself) ..

Comment: .. the value is copied into the method and changing it is not reflected outside at all. However sending it with the ref keyword will make any changes inside the method reflect on the original object as well.

Comment: Ok. Think I can just about get my head around that! Hadn't realised. Thank you for the explanation. So there is no way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: The only workaround is to make a Clone of your object before you send it into your method. In that case, only the cloned object will get changed, and not the original object. The clone has be made manually though. That is the only workaround to this "problem". I write "problem" since it's actually the expected behaviour ;)

Comment: Got it working in the end by just creating a new chart every time, rather than passing it - as there is no Clone method. Thanks for all your help and clear explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Check for Invoke Required in bcCharter_DoWork, if yes put the Clear method call in a delegate too.

```
 if (InvokeRequired)
 {          

     Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
     { 
       chart.Series.Clear();
       e.Result=chart;               
     }));

     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the analysis in the previous posts : you ask a thread to access to a resource of another thread.
Like you used a BackgroundWorker I suggest you to use the Dispatcher :

```
private void bcCharter_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Chart chart = null;

    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(() =>
            {
                chart.Series.Clear();
            }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is that you cannot access UI elements on threads other than the one they were created on.  However, in your case you can simply clear the chart before calling the background worker.

You can manually marshal UI element access to the correct thread from another thread using `Control.Invoke`.